# Oracle connect by find his immediate parent and his siblings

Tags: sql, oracle, siblings

```
Id          DepId
100         0
110         100
115         110
120         100
130         100
150         110
160         110
165         110
200         195
210         110
220         0
230         110
240         0
310         110
```

From this data, I need to query by `Id`, and get the results of the immediate parent and all their siblings

For example, if I search for the Id `115`, I should retrieve the rows of that person's parent record `110` and their siblings, like: `120`, `130`.

```
110         100
120         100
130         100
```

How do I get this results using oracle connect by?

Answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.ID, b.depid
FROM
(
    SELECT id, level mlevel
    FROM RULES
    WHERE LEVEL IN (2,3)
    START WITH ID in (115)
    CONNECT BY  ID = PRIOR depid
) A
JOIN RULES b
ON (A.ID = b.depid
    AND A.mlevel = 3) OR
    (A.ID = b.ID
    AND A.mlevel = 2)
```

Comment: `select Id, DeptId from Table where DeptId = (select DeptId from Table where Id = (select DeptId from Table where Id = 115))`

Comment: select Id, DepId from rules where DepId = (select DepId from rules where Id = (select DepId from rules where Id = 115)) 

This is working correctly for 115. 

For 110, it is returning too many rows which is not expected.
For 110, it should his parent 100 only

Comment: Ok starting to see why you want to use connect by but if it's always a constant depth no need to use connect by... `SELECT R3.* 
FROM RULES R1
INNER JOIN RULES R2
 on R1.DeptID = R2.ID
INNER JOIN RULES R3
 on R2.DeptID = R3.DeptID
WHERE R1.ID = 115`

Comment: change `CONNECT BY  ID = PRIOR depid` to `CONNECT BY  PRIOR depid= ID`

Comment: Put another way, you're after the all the grandparents children for a given ID.  In this data structure, the only way you know siblings is if they have the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have the connect by values in the wrong order.  ORDER matters in the connect by line.

but I would also re-write.

```
With RULES (ID, DepID) AS (

SELECT 100,         0 from dual union all
SELECT 110,         100 from dual union all
SELECT 115,         110 from dual union all
SELECT 120,         100 from dual union all
SELECT 130,         100 from dual union all
SELECT 150,         110 from dual union all
SELECT 160,         110 from dual union all
SELECT 165,         110 from dual union all
SELECT 200,         195 from dual union all
SELECT 210,         110 from dual union all
SELECT 220,         0 from dual union all
SELECT 230,         110 from dual union all
SELECT 240,         0 from dual union all
SELECT 310,         110 from dual )

SELECT * 
FROM RULES 
where DEPID in (
    SELECT id 
    FROM RULES
    WHERE LEVEL = 3
    Start with ID in (115)
    CONNECT BY PRIOR depid = id)
```

If you're always going back a set number of levels, then I would think just having the joins would be easier to understand/maintain

```
SELECT R3.* 
FROM RULES R1 
INNER JOIN RULES R2 
  on R1.DepID = R2.ID 
INNER JOIN RULES R3 
  on R2.DepID = R3.DepID 
WHERE R1.ID = 115
```